# aggregate data in columns with duplicate id in R

Tags: r, duplicates, aggregate

I have a df like this:

```
> dat
    gen M1  M1  M1  M1  M2  M2  M2
    G1  150     142 130 105 96  
    G2  150 145 142 130     96  89
    G3  150 145     130 105 96  
    G4      145 142 130 105     89
    G5  150     142 130 105 96  
    G6      145 142 130     96  89
    G7  150     142     105 96  
    G8  150 145     130 105     89
    G9  150 145 142         96  89
```

Here, data are present in duplicated ids. I like to aggergate like this:

```
>dat1
gen M1  M1  M1  M1  agg M2  M2  M2  agg
G1  150     142 130 150/142/130 105 96      105/96
G2  150 145 142 130 150/145/142/130     96  89  96/89
G3  150 145     130 150/145/130 105 96      105/96
G4      145 142 130 145/142/430 105     89  105/89
G5  150     142 130 150/142/130 105 96      105/96
G6      145 142 130 145/142/130     96  89  96/89
G7  150     142     150/142 105 96      105/96
G8  150 145     130 150/145/130 105     89  105/89
G9  150 145 142     150/145/142     96  89  96/89
```

here, in agg column i aggregated all the values based on duplicate first row. 
I like to create new column at the end of the duplicate columns and aggregate it.
How to do it in R. I am very confused

```
EDIT:
dput(dat)
    structure(list(V1 = structure(c(10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5", "G6", "G7", 
    "G8", "G9", "gen"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("150", "M1"), class = "factor"), 
        V3 = structure(c(2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("145", 
        "M1"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("142", "M1"), class = "factor"), 
        V5 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), .Label = c("130", 
        "M1"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("105", "M2"), class = "factor"), 
        V7 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("96", 
        "M2"), class = "factor"), V8 = structure(c(2L, NA, 1L, NA, 
        1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("89", "M2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
    "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L))
```

Comment: Your `dput(...)` is very odd. It puts the header in the first row, and has the column names as `V1, V2,...`. That is not what you question states as teh structure of `dat`.

Comment: I dunno how your data got like that, but it probably is not intentional. I can imagine alot could unintentionally go wrong with that setup. I would fix that first and then one of the answers below will work. If you cannot fix the data yourself, add something about how you import your data and we will give a try fixing it for you.

Comment: Thank you Guys. I apologize, here i used a simple example just to show how my df looks. Moreover, i just imported without header, thats y it automatically assigning header to each column. As you said, both of your answers works fine! I am quite aware of it! My actual question, is it possible to identify the duplicate column headers like M1 and aggregate without manually assigning col ids? Something putting it into for loop, I am confused how to advance in loop to next agg? or apply works, how to do with it? I think if v able to count no. of M1/M2/M3, then for loop work. let me know your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if the missing values are blanks:

```
dat$agg1 <- apply(dat[,2:5],1,function(x)paste(x[nchar(x)>0],collapse="/"))
dat$agg2 <- apply(dat[,6:8],1,function(x)paste(x[nchar(x)>0],collapse="/"))

dat <- dat[,c(1:5,9,6:8,10)]
dat
#   gen  M1 M1.1 M1.2 M1.3            agg1  M2 M2.1 M2.2   agg2
# 1  G1 150       142  130     150/142/130 105   96      105/96
# 2  G2 150  145  142  130 150/145/142/130       96   89  96/89
# 3  G3 150  145       130     150/145/130 105   96      105/96
# 4  G4      145  142  130     145/142/130 105        89 105/89
# ...
```

This works if the missing values are `NA`

```
dat$agg1 <- apply(dat[,2:5],1,function(x)paste(x[!is.na(x)],collapse="/"))
dat$agg2 <- apply(dat[,6:8],1,function(x)paste(x[!is.na(x)],collapse="/"))
```

Answer (score 0):

to aggregate them into a character vector you use paste()

```
 x=data.frame(x1=1:10,x2=1:10,x1=11:20)

 #now notice that r created my x object with three columns x1,x2 and x1.1

 xnew=cbind(x,agg=paste(x$x1,x$x2,x$x1.1,sep="/"))
```

I am not sure if this is what you want to do because I am a bit confused about the structure of your data.

Comment: Thanks Seth. In my df, I have M1 in 4 columns and M2 in 3 columns. In all the col i have values or NAs/blanks. I like to insert new col after each set of duplicate rows and aggregate it as in second df.

Comment: can you do a `dput(dat)` into your question vs the output of a `print(dat)`?

Comment: If you get your data into a proper data frame this answer or jlhoward

Answer (score 0):

Here is my script... I Know some of you guys can make it simple and elegant!
I transposed my df (a simple example) and read as table.

```
 > dat<-read.table("dat.txt", header=T, sep="\t", na.strings="")
    > dat
       gen  A  B  C  D
    1   M1  1 NA  3 NA
    2   M1 NA  6 NA  3
    3   M1  4  8 NA NA
    4   M1 NA NA  6  3
    5   M2  8 NA  6 NA
    6   M2 NA  2 NA  6
    7   M3  3  8 NA  2
    8   M3  8  9  5 NA
    9   M4  3  7  8  5
    10  M4  5 NA  3  2
    > final<-NULL
    > for(i in 1:4){
    +   mar<-as.character(dat[1,1])
    +   dat1<-dat[dat[,1]%in% c(mar),]
    +   dat <- dat[!dat[,1]%in% c(mar),]
    +   dat2 <- apply(dat1,2,function(x)paste(x[!is.na(x)],collapse="/"))
    +   dat2$gen<-mar
    +   dat3<-rbind(dat1,dat2)
    +   final<-rbind(final, dat3)
    + }
    Warning messages:
    1: In dat2$gen <- mar : Coercing LHS to a list
    2: In dat2$gen <- mar : Coercing LHS to a list
    3: In dat2$gen <- mar : Coercing LHS to a list
    4: In dat2$gen <- mar : Coercing LHS to a list
    > final
       gen     A     B     C     D
    1   M1     1  <NA>     3  <NA>
    2   M1  <NA>     6  <NA>     3
    3   M1     4     8  <NA>  <NA>
    4   M1  <NA>  <NA>     6     3
    5   M1  1/ 4  6/ 8  3/ 6  3/ 3
    51  M2     8  <NA>     6  <NA>
    6   M2  <NA>     2  <NA>     6
    31  M2     8     2     6     6
    7   M3     3     8  <NA>     2
    8   M3     8     9     5  <NA>
    32  M3   3/8   8/9     5     2
    9   M4     3     7     8     5
    10  M4     5  <NA>     3     2
    33  M4   3/5     7   8/3   5/2
```